# Multiple Choice Exam with randomized answers: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, random, 2d

I am trying to make an exam that has multiple "pools" of questions that I need to randomly pull a specific number out of and shuffle with the other pools. I have gotten close. I have tried two methods a random splice and a random value. When I use the splice it seems to flatten my 2d array, question and answers. The random value gives me duplicate items.

This one seems to "flatten the array" and return the question and answers as the same item.

> ```
> Array.prototype.randsplice = function() {
>   var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
>   //takes it out of the array
>   var rs = this.splice(ri, 1);
>   return rs
> }
> ```
>
> This one retruns the array correctly but gives me dupilcate items.
>
> ```
> Array.prototype.randval = function() {
>   var ri = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length);
>   var val = this[ri];
>   return val;
> }
>
> Array.prototype.shuffle = function(){
>     var i = this.length, j, temp;
>     while(--i > 0){
>         j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i+1));
>         temp = this[j];
>         this[j] = this[i];
>         this[i] = temp;
>     }
>     return this;
> }
>
> Array.prototype.clean = function(deleteValue) {
>   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
>     if (this[i] == deleteValue) {
>       this.splice(i, 1);
>       i--;
>     }
>   }
>   return this;
> };
> ```

QUESTION ARRAYS

```
var pos = 0,
    test, test_status, question, choice, choices, chA, chB, chC,
    correct = 0;
var questions = [
    ["What is 10 + 4?", "12", "14", "16", "B"],
    ["What is 20 - 9?", "7", "13", "11", "C"],
    ["What is 7 x 3?", "21", "24", "25", "A"],
    ["What is 8 / 2?", "10", "10", "4", "C"]
];
var questions2 = [
    ["What is A?", "A", "B", "C", "A"],
    ["What is B?", "A", "B", "C", "B"],
    ["What is C?", "A", "B", "C", "C"],
    ["What is D?", "B", "C", "D", "C"]
];
```

COMBINING ARRAYS

```
var newArray = [];
var newArray2 = [];

function myFunction() {
    newArray.push(result);
    newArray2.push(result2);
    return newArray;
    return newArray2;
}
```

Will need different numbers used per pool

> ```
> var pool1NumUsed = 2;
> for (i = 0; i < pool1NumUsed; i++) {
>   //alert("For loop 1"/*questions.length*/);
>   var result = questions.randsplice();
>   var result2 = questions2.randsplice();
>   myFunction();
> }
> var resultCleaned = result.clean();
> var combinedArrays = newArray.concat(newArray2).clean();
> var combinedArraysRand = combinedArrays.shuffle();
> ```

I need to be able to pull a specific number of questions from each pool, I will have more that 2 pools in the final, and then shuffle them all together.
In the end product I will also need to shuffle the answers/distractors (will need to be able to turn this function on and off per question. Questions with numeric answers will need to be in order from lowest to highest.), build a remediation page, and get a score.
Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Pen [Full Code](https://codepen.io/cog42/pen/mpGzyr)

Comment: Please try to reduce your code to a specific problem you've got by following the guidelines how to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I think I condensed it enough to comply. Full code to see functionality is on CodePen. See link in post.

Comment: I might of found a "simpler" way to accomplish this. Instead of looping through the arrays and picking random numbers I shuffled the question pools individually and then sliced the 1st - however many items I needed. then i concatenated the pools and shuffled them again.
Made a new Pen https://codepen.io/cog42/pen/vpzogw?editors=1000